# Restart macro after it is finished

Tags: vba, excel

So, I have this really simple macro:

```
Sub timer()
Application.OnTime TimeValue("00:00:00"), "Envios"
End Sub
```

Made in Excel. All I need is a code to make it run everytime it finishes its tasks, so I can run the sub "Envios" everyday at midnight. Could you give a help with it? Thank you very much!

Comment: If you have a windows system you could use the task scheduler, put the code of Envios in the the workbook_open event and open it every day at midnight.

Comment: @Storax, I tried to do this, but didn't find the right path to where I should add this task...

Comment: The task scheduler is part of the operating system. have a look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx) or look for [How to](https://www.howtogeek.com/123393/how-to-automatically-run-programs-and-set-reminders-with-the-windows-task-scheduler/)